# Preventing the Big Bang

Tags: internal-consistency, hard-science, time-travel

I travel back in time to the Big Bang in my time machine. I am equipped with all the present day equipment I need. I locate the infinitesimal 'point' where the Universe would come into existence and  bombard it with elementary particles so as to prevent the random singularity that was the Big Bang from occurring.

**Question**

Ignoring time-travel paradoxes and what happens to me after I have stopped the Big Bang, have I succeeded in preventing the Universe coming into existence?

Comment: *"I locate the infinitesimal 'point' where the Universe would come into existence":* that's really not that hard, given that when the Big Bang happened that point was the entire universe. Which is to say, travelling back in time is enough -- starting from any point and just going back in time you will reach the Big Bang. The real problem is that immediately after the Big Bang the physical conditions prevailing did not allow for the existence of atoms (or the usual electrons, protons etc.)... You may find it hard to use the equipment when both you and the equipment are a soup of quarks.

Comment: There's no "time" before the big bang. To be a tiny bit more scientific you could time travel to a  tiny fraction of a second (10^-32) and potentially change something.

Comment: @CptLasky While there are cosmological models that assume time began with the Big Bang, there are other cosmological models where time existed before the Big Bang. You can be scientific either way. It's not unreasonable to grant the OP that in his fictional universe there is time before the Big Bang.

Comment: hard-science tag man? eh? no way you need it in the situation, or no way you could expect it being useful here

Answer (score 6):

No, because *by definition* you can never get to the initial singularity, and there wasn't a singularity or a "time before", anyway.

As @Renan correctly noted, it's a mistake to think that things started with an empty universe with a Singularity bopping into existence and then exploding to release all of the matter and energy we observe today into the emptiness.  As you go into the past, the universe (whether finite or infinite) is *always* completely filled. As it ages, spacetime itself is expanding and diluting the matter and energy of the universe as it does. And if you could travel backwards in time, the reverse would be happening and spacetime would be shrinking and matter and energy would be growing more dense.

This is a consequence of the mathematics of Einstein's General Relativity, a lovely theory which proves 100%-correct every time we've been able to test it, so we have great confidence when we use it to extrapolate backwards to predict (retrodict?) conditions are earlier times. **But:** When you work backwards you eventually come to a mathematical singularity, and such a singularity is not a *prediction* of General Relativity, but an unmistakable sign that the theory fails under those conditions. *At high enough densities and small enough distances General Relativity fails as a theory.* We know this. What we don't know is what the better theory is that *does* explain phenomena at very small distances and very high energies.

This is a hot topic of current research and it's fair to say that we have many clues and several candidate theories and we  *know* that none of them are correct -- yet. We're pretty sure that we need a complete quantum theory of gravity to succeed General Relativity, but we don't have one. Maybe someday. (Don't hold your breath -- it's a very, very hard problem.)

We have a number of lines of reasoning which allow us to estimate where GR breaks down and it turns out that while that point is still a long way from the start of the expansion. GR is still valid at a point where we have reached conditions (which we understand in pretty good detail and are pretty confident of) where elementary particles like protons are not stable. All the matter in the universe is reduced to a ["quark-gluon plasma"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark%E2%80%93gluon_plasma) and whatever your time machine is made of, it's dissolved into free quarks and gluons.

You're dissolved into hot elementary particles and you're still nowhere near the start of the expansion.

Answer (score 5):

Nope.

You can't go outside the universe and [it was was smaller than you by orders of magnitude](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/31264) at the absolute beginning of time. You just don't fit.

> Imagine measuring our current universe by drawing out a grid with spacing of 1 light year. Although obviously we can't do this, you can easily imagine putting the Earth at $(0, 0)$, Alpha Centauri at $(4.37, 0)$ and plotting out all the stars on this grid. The key thing is that this grid is infinite$^1$, i.e., there is no point where you can't extend the grid any further.
>
> Now wind time back to 7 billion years after the big bang, i.e. about halfway back. Our grid now has a spacing of half a light year, but it's still infinite - there is still no edge to it. The average spacing between objects on the universe has reduced by half and the average density has gone up by a factor of $2^3$.
>
> Now wind back to 0.0000000001 seconds after the big bang. There's no special significance to that number; it's just meant to be extremely small. Our grid now has a very small spacing, but it's still infinite. No matter how close we get to the Big Bang we still have an infinite grid filling all of space. You may have heard pop science programmes describing the Big Bang as *happening everywhere* and this is what they mean. The universe didn't shrink down to a point at the Big Bang, it's just that **the spacing between any two randomly selected spacetime points shrank down to zero.**
>
> So at the Big Bang we have the very odd situation where the spacing between every point in the universe is zero, but the universe is still infinite. **The total size of the universe is then $0 \times \infty$, which is undefined**. You probably think this doesn't make sense, and actually most physicists agree with you. The Big Bang is a [**singularity**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_singularity) (...)

Even if you would send only those particles, they would just add more mass-energy to the universe. We'd have a marginally more massive universe, but that's it.

Comment: **Many** orders of magnitude... And there is no such thing as "prior" to the event.

Comment: @AlexP thanks, I've corrected it.

Comment: We don't actually know that the universe is infinite, though there is some decent evidence that it's at least ten times bigger than the part we can see.  (This is quibblish inasmuch as it being finite-but-really-big doesn't really affect the central point of the argument here.)

Comment: 1e-10 seconds after Big Bang? Lots happened well before then. You're already *well* into the quark epoch by that time. Compare [Wikipedia: Chronology of the universe: Very early universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_the_universe#Very_early_universe).

Answer (score -2):

Lets assume that we had no singularity.

The metaverse is an infinite expanse,  with new locally connected universes forming from critical fluctuations that crystalize into instabilities in the metauniverse's inflation field.   Universes expand from the instabilities like bubbles forming in thick, boiling oatmeal.

There is an "outside" -- the region containing the instability -- and time exists before the bubble universe forms.

To cancel the "big bang" one could travel to before the critical moment and disrupt the instability to prevent universe from forming, or perhaps even sculpt to a new reality the new universe to be.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/58831)

Comment: Thd last sentence is the answer.

Comment: The OP specifically posited a situation and you have not addressed it.  Nor have you met the mandate for the [tag:hard-science] tag, which is required for an answer.

Comment: Since at the inception of an in instability the variation from the background condition is infinitesimal, very little is required to disrupt it from growing.  A backfround inflation field with bubble universes is well within current physics theoretical exploration, and is attractive because it avoids singularities.  The missing piece is the ability to travel through the inflation quantum field, but if we have solved time travel, it is detail for the experentalists.

Comment: @cmm, those speculation, while normally acceptable for other answers here, do not meet the hard science specifications, which state that answers shall be backed up by equations, empirical evidence, scientific papers, other citations, etc.